Choosing the right CMS
I am tasked with replacing a heavily-customized Wordpress-based website at our organization. While the existing site was lauded for being very light on desktop and mobile browsers alike, it is basically un-editable except in raw HTML+CSS since the previous webmaster left the organization in very bad terms and didn't leave the administrator password. Previously, the organization's website was a stock Wordpress (plus a few, mostly cosmetic plugins) that got repeatedly defaced, most likely by automated tools, that required the previous webmaster to eliminate extra files by hand and be constantly on the lookout for signs of infection that would reoccur every week.
As the website will have to serve as a communication tool, it is simply not realistic to expect every member of the organization to edit HTML files by hand to push new content (this isn't 1995!), nor should they rely on the webmaster to do so. Nor it is realistic to expect the first employee to come on Mondays to restore the latest known-good backup in order to eliminate the infection. That would be a workaround, not a proper solution.
The context

Shared hosting (We also have a VPS for a different tool should it become necessary);
Employees don't have any experience managing Web-based tools and applications;
Wordpress is known to be a prime target for automated defacing;
Privacy laws still aren't well understood. That means we tend to err on the side of caution and that the webmaster-to-be won't have access to the VPS, and may not even have access to the shared hosting administrative interface, despite being signed into an NDA (that's a whole other problem that will have to be solved).

The goals

Any employee should be able to log in, write their content and publish it;
The chosen CMS shouldn't require an unreasonable amount of maintenance time;
The writing interface should be simple enough that anyone with a basic understanding of text formatting is able to write content;
Easy update: the CMS shouldn't require any "risky" operation like updating, say, Mattermost (which requires kicking everyone out, switch to maintenance to prevent automated re-login, and manually replace files in-place)
Generate standards-compliant pages;
The chosen CMS has to be open-source (this isn't negotiable).

The candidates:
Wordpress
Advantage
Widely-used means a much larger community. An abundance of resources available, tons of plugins, including ones linking to other social networks.
Downside

Too many plugins! It's hard to know which ones are reliable or compatible.
From experience, a prime target for defacing; code doesn't seem robust enough.

Dotclear
Advantage

Very stable, a good amount of relevant plugins
Lightweight

Downside

Obscure malfunctions in spam filtering means that bots still go through with posting irrelevant comments
Smaller community
Blog-oriented.

Drupal
Advantage

I read somewhere that it clearly distinguishes between roles: technical, localization, content publisher, art worker, etc. This would mean easier compliance with restrictive interpretation of privacy laws.

Downside

convoluted setup?

Spip
Advantage

Used by big names in the publishing industry
very flexible

Downside

Requires the use of skeletons for layouts, which requires an additional learning effort

Joomla
Advantage
unknown
Downside

More technical than others.

CMS Made simple
Advantage

Each function is independent from the others: templates, content, style sheet, would make it more flexible

Downside
Textpattern
Advantage

Lightweight
Passes strict HTML validation.

Downside

Not WYSIWYG. On the other hand, Markdown-style markup isn't very complicated.

unknown
TYPO3
Advantage

Widely used in large organizations
Therefore, I assume it's very stable

Downside

If it fits the needs of larger organizations, I also assume it's also rather complex.

Needless to say, I haven't personally tried them all. What other points should I take into account, or points I missed here?

At the end of the day Wordpress is what different types of users can really work on (managment, content, design, support, marketing). If you install WP on a hosting that includes automated backups (of files and database) your worries on defacements, infections and the like are reduced.

I assume they'll all feature some sort of access control as it's a vital part of any CMS.  Joomla give you more options that Wordpress for creating user groups, for example.

It's going to depend what your content is. Pick the one that has most of what you need out-of-the-box.
If it's blog-like content, then WordPress may be your best option.  Drupal and Joomla are more for bespoke layouts and brochure sites.  They're also more powerful frameworks for coding large sites with, but WordPress makes a good blog.
A few things to be wary of:

Third party plug-ins tend to be where hackers get in.  Larger, well-known plug-ins are usually fine if kept patched, and bespoke plug-ins are less likely to suffer any automated attack.  It's the small plug-ins that are usually why sites get hacked.  If you use third party plug-ins, it's vital they you keep them patched and remove them if they become unsupported.
I assume a hack is what you mean by "defaced".  Deleting files will not fix such a hack - you have to find where the hacker got in and fix that.  It's likely they have a backdoor somewhere still on your site. When a hacker is already on the site, patching will make no difference.
If you have database access, you can actually get administrator access to a WordPress site by changing the password there.

Are you a coder yourself?  If you aren't able to write your own plug-ins, and don't want to hire a developer, you may be better with Wix or SquareSpace, as at least they are going to be secure and simple to update (if limited).
It sounds like your big problem at the moment is a lack of understanding of security. You need to understand that if you plan to develop with any of these systems, and want to avoid being hacked.
